# DataTable inside DataSet not having the same information

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I understand that a dataset is just a list of datatables, and any changes made to a particular datatable will be reflected in the dataset.

I created a class containing, amongst others, some tables and a dataset.
Here is some part of the constructor:

```
    public class Docket_Patent_Rec_Data : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
    {
        public DataTable General;
        public DataTable Applicants;
        public DataTable Instances;
        public DataTable Instructions;

        public Docket_Patent_Rec_Data()
        {
            General = new DataTable("General");
            Applicants = new DataTable("Applicants");
            Instances = new DataTable("Instances");
            Instructions = new DataTable("Instructions");

            Docket_DataSet = new DataSet();
            Docket_DataSet.Tables.Add(General);
            Docket_DataSet.Tables.Add(Applicants);
            Docket_DataSet.Tables.Add(Instances);
            Docket_DataSet.Tables.Add(Instructions);
        }
    }
```

I added created an instanced name PreApp_Case and added some rows to the table 'Applicants'.

However, when debbuging, VS shows the following:

```
PreApp_Case.Docket_DataSet.Tables["Applicants"].Rows.Count
0
PreApp_Case.Applicants.Rows.Count
3
```

I don't understand what's going on, as the dataset is just a pointer to the different tables and does not have different tables.

Comment: really hard to determine what the issue is here without seeing how you loaded the tables can you show all relevant code..?

Comment: What ever is causing the problem is not in the code you posted.

Comment: Steve and DJ are right, I tried your code, worked perfect